# How to create a Child Story and associate it with a Parent User Story using Rally REST API?

Tags: vb.net, rest, rally

I'm using the Rally REST API to integrate user story data from Rally into another application. I understand how to create a Story and associate it with a Workspace, Project and Iteration, but how do I insert it as a Child Story and associate it with another Parent Story. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
Dim restApi As RallyRestApi = RunTimeConfig.GetRallyApi()
Dim djo As New DynamicJsonObject()
djo("Name") = cs.StoryName
djo("Description") = cs.StoryDesc
djo("WorkSpace") = "/workspace/" & pj.WorkspaceID
djo("Project") = "/project/" & pj.ProjectID
djo("Iteration") = "/iteration/" & it.SprintID
djo("Parent") = "/hierarchicalrequirement/" & par.UserStoryID
Dim re As CreateResult = restApi.Create("hierarchicalrequirement", djo)
```

The above throws a KeyNotFound exception.

I have also tried to create the story first and then update it as following:

```
Dim toUpdate As New DynamicJsonObject()
toUpdate("Parent") = "/hierarchicalrequirement/" & par.UserStoryID
Dim result As OperationResult = restApi.Update(re.Reference, toUpdate)
```

Which still doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the REST API are you using?  The KeyNotFoundException is likely the result of a bug in an earlier version of the library around parsing errors.  What is likely happening is the create is failing but the CreateResult is not parsing the returned errors correctly.  I'd recommend upgrading to the latest version available here:

http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rest-api-net

Comment: +1 on Kyle's recommendation. Your code snippet looks spot-on. I ran an analogous VB example using the 1.07 REST .NET DLL, and it worked great. It could be that there's a Rally issue (permissions, etc.) that is causing the error but isn't being reported accurately due to the bug Kyle mentions.